# JButtons don't load on panel until hovered over?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

When this is put on a frame, the buttons don't load until they are hovered over with the mouse, and then they stay up like they should. Here's the code:
I've calling things like repaint() and revalidate() but none of them seem to have fixed the problem. The main and the Frame are seperate classes from the StartPanel. Thanks!

```
JButton[][] levels = new JButton[3][8]; 

public StartPanel(){
    setSize(1600, 1000);
    setLayout(null);

    int count = 1;
    int yValue = 150;
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++){
            levels[r][c] = new JButton(String.valueOf(count));
            levels[r][c].setLocation(c*190 + 80, yValue);
            levels[r][c].setSize(100, 100);
            this.add(levels[r][c]);
            count++;
        }
        yValue += 200;
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f = new Frame();
    StartPanel sp = new StartPanel();
    f.add(sp);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public Frame() {
    setSize(1600, 1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setResizable(false);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of the rest of your code?

Comment: `setLayout(null);` <- There's your problem. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Okay thanks, I had a feeling that was it. What layout would you recommend? I had thought maybe GridLayout but I want to have space in between the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

## GridLayout

I might suggest trying `GridLayout`, in combination with something like an `EmptyBorder`, you should be able to get close to what you want, for example...

[image: Buttons]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        JButton[][] levels = new JButton[3][8];

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 40, 40, 40));
            setSize(1600, 1000);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 8, 40, 40));

            int count = 1;
            int yValue = 150;
            for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
                    levels[r][c] = new JButton(String.valueOf(count));
                    levels[r][c].setMargin(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));
                    this.add(levels[r][c]);
                    count++;
                }
                yValue += 200;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

See [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more details

## GridBagLayout

Another solution might be to use a `GridBagLayout`, which is more flexible, but also more complicated, for example...

[image: More Buttons]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        JButton[][] levels = new JButton[3][8];

        public TestPane() {
            setSize(1600, 1000);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            int count = 1;
            for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
                    levels[r][c] = new JButton(String.valueOf(count));
                    levels[r][c].setMargin(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));
                    this.add(levels[r][c], gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                    count++;
                }
                gbc.gridy++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah that it like something I was looking for. I wasn't sure how to put spacing in between them. Thanks again!

Comment: There's generally more than one way to skin this cat ;)

Comment: @DerekSchuster Also note `EventQueue.invokeLater`. This is how you make changes in the UI in Swing ([other methods are available as well](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)). Don't make UI changes in **your** threads. All changes must be made in the UI thread, this is what these methods are for ;)

Comment: @DerekSchuster Did you run the exact code as I posted or did you modify your existing code?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I figured it out. It won't let me use the paint(Graphics g) with my panel now. When I add the method it goes back to not loading any of the buttons. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @DerekSchuster Yeah, cause `paint` is responsible for painting everything...you shouldn't be overriding it when the component contains child components, as it can screw with the paint chain (I bet you're not calling `super.paint` are you...)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Haha okay that makes sense. So then if I wanted to paint something within the panel how would I go about doing that? Also, if I want to remove this panel and add on a new one, how would I do that? I'm just confused because this panel is added within the EventQueue.invokeLater(). Could this panel be added outside of this? Thanks again for all this help

Comment: *"Could this panel be added outside of this?"* - No, never, nutta.  All modifications, updates and changes to the UI MUST be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. *"So then if I wanted to paint something within the panel how would I go about doing that?"* - That would depend on what it is you are trying to achieve. *" if I want to remove this panel and add on a new one, how would I do that?"* - `Container#remove`, `Container#add` or use a `CardLayout`, depending on what you are trying to do...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm going for something like a CardLayout because I need two panels to alternate between each other. One has the buttons and another will paint things to the screen. Should I try a CardLayout or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay I'll try to work that out. Thanks for all your help