# JButton Hidden Until Hovered First Startup

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel, jbutton

Note that I have found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843703/jbuttons-dont-load-on-panel-until-hovered-over), but this question seems to be having this problem consistantly and didn't really offer an explination as to WHY this occurs, only an alternate approach.

I'm creating a Stratego game, and right now I am creating boards where a play can swap around their pieces and then submit the board layout as their army starting locations.

I have a single JButton on each of the frames (one for each player, the second shows up after the first player has submited and left the computer), and the JButton on the first frame only is hidden until you hover it, but only the first time that the program runs after Eclipse is opened.

Can someone give an explination as to why this occurs?

The Main running class

```
LogicInterpreter logic = new LogicInterpreter();

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    InputFrame inputPlayer1 = new InputFrame(logic, 1, "red", 600, 600);
    inputPlayer1.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - inputPlayer1.getSize().width/2,
            dim.height / 2 - inputPlayer1.getSize().height / 2);

    while(!logic.isSetUp1()){
        //Just to make it work
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Now bring up board 2

    InputFrame inputPlayer2 = new InputFrame(logic, 2, "blue", 600, 600);
    inputPlayer2.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - inputPlayer2.getSize().width/2,
            dim.height / 2 - inputPlayer2.getSize().height / 2);

    while(!logic.isSetUp2()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Will eventually open the main board
    openBoards(logic);
}
```

This is the relevant setup code for the input frames

```
public class InputFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private LogicInterpreter holder;
private Panel2 jp;
private int height, width;
private Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> lakeCoords = new HashMap<>();
private List<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<>();
private int playernumber;
private String playerColor;
Piece selectedPiece;
Piece secondSelectedPiece;
boolean hidePieces = false;

JButton submit = new JButton("SUBMIT");

public void addCoords() {
    lakeCoords.put(3, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(6, 5)));
    lakeCoords.put(4, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(6, 5)));
    lakeCoords.put(7, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(6, 5)));
    lakeCoords.put(8, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(6, 5)));
}

public void createPieces() {
    int y = 1;

    if (playernumber == 2) {
        y = 6;
    }

    List<Integer> openValues = new ArrayList<>();

    openValues.add(1);
    openValues.add(2);
    openValues.add(11);
    openValues.add(12);
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        openValues.add(3);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        openValues.add(4);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        openValues.add(5);
        openValues.add(6);
        openValues.add(7);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        openValues.add(8);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        openValues.add(9);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        openValues.add(10);
    }

    Collections.sort(openValues);
    for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        for (int z = y; z <= 4; z++) {

            // 1x1 Marshal
            // 2x1 General
            // 3x2 Colonel
            // 4x3 Major
            // 5x4 Captain
            // 6x4 Lieutenant
            // 7x4 Sergeant
            // 8x5 Miner
            // 9x8 Scout
            // 10x6 Bomb
            // 11x1 Flag
            // 12x1 Spy

            Piece piece = new Piece(new Coords(x, z), openValues.get(0), playerColor);

            openValues.remove(0);
            pieces.add(piece);
        }
    }
}

public InputFrame(LogicInterpreter holder, int playerNumber, String playerColor, int height, int width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    playernumber = playerNumber;
    this.playerColor = playerColor;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addCoords();
    this.holder = holder;
    createPieces();
    jp = new Panel2(height, width);
    setResizable(false);
    jp.setBackground(new Color(235, 202, 158));
    setTitle("Player " + playerNumber + " Arrangement GUI     ||     Click Submit When Ready");
    jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    jp.setLayout(null);
    jp.addMouseListener(new HandleMouse());
    getContentPane().add(jp);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    if(playernumber == 1)
        submit.setBounds(width / 10 * 4, height / 10 * 7, width / 10 * 2, height / 10 * 2);
    else
        submit.setBounds(width / 10 * 4, height / 10, width / 10 * 2, height / 10 * 2);
    submit.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, width * 20 / 600));
    submit.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    submit.addActionListener(new CloseListener(this));
    jp.add(submit);
}

//More stuff down here about logic and stuff

public class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;

    public Panel2(int height, int width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += width / 10) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y += height / 10) {
                boolean fill = false;
                for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> coords : lakeCoords.entrySet()) {
                    if ((coords.getKey() - 1 == x / 60 && coords.getValue().get(0) - 1 == y / 60)
                            || (coords.getKey() - 1 == x / 60 && coords.getValue().get(1) - 1 == y / 60)) {
                        fill = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fill) {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.fillRect(x, y, width / 10, height / 10);
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.drawRect(x, y, width / 10, height / 10);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.drawRect(x, y, width / 10, height / 10);
                }
            }
        }

        if(hidePieces){
            for (Piece piece : pieces) {
                try {
                    g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File(playerColor + "_pieces/" + (playerColor.equals("blue") ? "Blue" : "Red") + "_Strat_Piece"
                            + ".png")), piece.getX() * width / 10 - width / 10,
                            piece.getY() * height / 10 - height / 10, width / 10, height / 10, null);
                } catch(Exception e){}
            }
        } else {
            for (Piece piece : pieces) {
                g.drawImage(piece.getImage(), piece.getX() * width / 10 - width / 10,
                        piece.getY() * height / 10 - height / 10, width / 10, height / 10, null);
            }

            if (selectedPiece != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawImage(selectedPiece.getImage(), selectedPiece.getX() * width / 10 - width / 10,
                        selectedPiece.getY() * height / 10 - height / 10, width / 10, height / 10, null);
                g.drawRect(selectedPiece.getX() * width / 10 - width / 10,
                        selectedPiece.getY() * height / 10 - height / 10, width / 10, height / 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setVisible(true);

....

jp.add(submit); // Note the add() is after the setVisible()
```

> and the JButton on the first frame only is hidden until you hover it, but only the first time that the program runs after Eclipse is opened.

This implies that you are making the frame visible BEFORE adding all the components to the frame.

So the order of the basic logic is:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(...);
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swing components have to be created in EDT. Calling sleep() is EDT will block the UI and is never a good idea. See this for details on EDT: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html